# Setting Up livestreamer to Automatically Record twitch Streams

Tags: python, twitch

I have been looking for a way to record streams whilst not at home as past broadcasts are unsatisfactory to me with all their muted sections. I had a found one site to help get me started but when i went to check for replies to after commenting asking for help and including images of my script i see that my posting got deleted rather than answered. But i digress.

I know how to manually start livestreamer from the command prompt when the stream is live but as aforementioned i am looking for a solution for when i'm not home.

I am sharing what i have in the hopes that someone would be able to identify what is wrong and help me rectify all issues to get this working.

```
#This script checks if a user on twitch is currently streaming and then records the stream via livestreamer

from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError
from threading import Timer
import time
import datetime
import json
import sys
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import configparser

def check_user(user):
    """ returns 0: online, 1: offline, 2: not found, 3: error """
    global info
    url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + user +"/?client_id=###"
    try:
        info = json.loads(urlopen(url, timeout = 15).read().decode('utf-8'))
        if info['stream'] == None:
            status = 1
        else:
            status = 0
    except URLError as e:
        if e.reason == 'Not Found' or e.reason == 'Unprocessable Entity':
            status = 2
        else:
            status = 3
    return status

def format_filename(fname):
# Removes invalid characters from filename
    fname = fname.replace("/","")
    fname = fname.replace("?","")
    fname = fname.replace(":","-")
    fname = fname.replace("\\","")
    fname = fname.replace("<","")
    fname = fname.replace(">","")
    fname = fname.replace("*","")
    fname = fname.replace("\"","")
    fname = fname.replace("|","")
    fname = fname.replace(" ","")
    return fname


def loopcheck():
    while True:
        status = check_user(user)
        if status == 2:
            print("username not found. invalid username?")
        elif status == 3:
            print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Hh%Mm%Ss")," ","unexpected error. will try again in 5 minutes.")
            time.sleep(300)
        elif status == 1:
            print(user,"currently offline, checking again in",refresh,"seconds")
            time.sleep(refresh) # 15 seconds
        elif status == 0:
            print(user,"online. stop.")
            filename = user+" - "+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %Hh%Mm%Ss")+" - "+(info['stream']).get("channel").get("status")+".mp4"
            filename = format_filename(filename)
            str1="livestreamer --twitch-oauth-token ### twitch.tv/"+user+" "+quality+" -o "+directory+filename
            subprocess.call(str1)
            print("Stream is done. Going back to checking..")
            time.sleep(15)

def main():
    global refresh
    global user
    global quality
    global directory

    print("Usage: check.py [refresh] [user] [quality]")
    print("Usage: TwitchChecker.py [refresh] [user] [quality]")

    refresh = 15.0

    str1=""
    refresh = 15.0
    user = "###"
    quality = "best"
    directory = "C:\Users\###\Videos\###\\"


    if(refresh<15):
        print("Check interval should not be lower than 15 seconds")
        refresh=15

    print("Checking for",user,"every",refresh,"seconds. Record with",quality,"quality.")
    loopcheck()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()

set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
```

For the batch file i have:

```
@echo
C:\Python\python C:\Users\xxx\Videos\xxx\xxx.py 
@echo off
```

All that happens when i click on either of the 2 files is that the command prompt window flashes quickly.

Thankies for any and all help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as text. Images are discouraged

Comment: Add this after your python command `set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...` It will add pause. I am thinking that there is an error that is being hidden.

Comment: Thankies for the reviews.

I added that line at the very end but the command prompt just flashes and disappears. I'm in Windows 10 if that means anything. This is the first and only script i've ever tried working with so i have no experience in this matter.